# How do I get the contents of a big_map through the RPC interface?

Tags: smart-contracts, rpc, bigmap

I'm trying to view the contents of a big_map in the storage of a smart contract. However, querying my Tezos node doesn't seem to provide that information. Is there a way of using the RPC interface to directly obtain the elements contained within a big_map?

Answer (score 5):

As of 004_Pt24m4xi:

You can use the [big_map_get RPC](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-context-contracts-contract-id-big-map-get) to get individual values out.

There is also a `tezos-client` command for this. (By passing `-l` we can see how it works through the RPC.)

```
$ tezos-client -l get big map value for 1 of type nat in KT1Qu32f8N5RLPoku5n8itiGaJ1a3eJDj5gu
...
>>>>2: http://localhost:18731/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1Qu32f8N5RLPoku5n8itiGaJ1a3eJDj5gu/big_map_get
  { "key": { "int": "1" }, "type": { "prim": "nat" } }
<<<<2: 200 OK
  { "int": "2" }
2
```

---

It is also possible to use the [binary raw context RPC](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-raw-bytes) to explore the entire contents of the big_map, all at once or in pieces. I won't go into the details; they are difficult and seem out of scope. The relevant path is:

```
/chains/main/blocks/head/context/raw/bytes/contracts/index/...path/to/your/contract.../big_map
```

**Be careful.** If you experiment with `context/raw/bytes` outside of a sandbox, **use `?depth=1` to avoid overloading your node** by requesting the entire context at once.

The `depth` query parameter also enables you to scan the contents of a very large big_map, over multiple requests.

---

The protocol does not store the actual keys of the big_map in the context. It only stores the hashes of the keys. This means you cannot obtain the actual entries in the big_map (particularly, the keys) without either:

1. Scanning (non-pruned!) blocks in the chain for operation receipts of transfers to your contract, which include the `big_map_diff` with the actual keys, or
2. just knowing the keys somehow, and hashing them to find the corresponding entries.

As a hack, to waste some space in exchange for convenience, it is possible to store the unhashed key again inside the value. Then scanning the contents with `context/raw/bytes` can reveal the keys.